# I want create a Connect forwarding to SSH server with library on website www.bitvise.com

Tags: c#, ssh, proxy, socks, .net-framework-version

I created a connect to SSH server forwarding with library "FlowSshNet64_Framework40.dll" (my operating system is 64 bit) in C# but while I'm running error after import library to application and follow the instructions:

https://www.bitvise.com/fsd-client

```
Bitvise.FlowSshNet.Client t = new Client();
t.SetProxyHost("66.172.203.200");
t.SetProxyOptions(true);
t.SetProxyUserName("admin");
t.SetProxyPassword("admin");
t.SetProxyPort(22);
t.SetProxyType(ProxyType.Socks5);
ForwardingRule setup = new ForwardingRule();
setup.ClientToServer = true;
setup.ListInterface = "127.0.0.1";
setup.ListPort = 1080;
ForwardingHandler setup1 = new ForwardingHandler();
if (setup1.IsDisposed)
{
    t.AddForwarding(setup, setup1);
    label1.Text = "connected";
}
```

Picture of the error: [image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use FlowSshNet32_Framework40.dll on the os 64 bit

to run this you must copy all file to same directory such as bin\Debug. I do it and it doesn't have error

```
Binaries\CiProv32.dll
Binaries\CryptoPP530Fips32.dll
Binaries\FlowSshC32.dll
Binaries\FlowSshNet32_Framework40.dll -> RENAME THIS FILE TO: FlowSshNet32.dll
```

But i use your code and it not forwarding to ssh